# How can i fix the errors in my registration script

Tags: php, authentication

Im getting an error on line 4, The curly bracket. From what i know the bracket needs to be there. How can i fix this ?

```
<?php
include('config.php');
// for the registration script we need a html form
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' {
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));
//retrieve the input from the user and encrypt the password with md5
 } if(empty($username)) {
echo("Please enter a Username");
} else {
if(empty($password)) {
echo("Please enter a password");
} else {
//check if username already exists
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
//with mysql_query you call a sql command 
if($rows > 0) {
    die("Username taken !!");
    } else {
    $user_input = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username , password) VALUES     ('$username' , '$password')");
    echo("Successfully Registered ");
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: In which environment do you program? Maybe Netbeans is a idea? It will help you with debugging.

Comment: I use notepad++ Ive tried other programmes like aptana studio and netbeans, but i honestly prefer notepad++ just because of its simplicity

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' {
```

To

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
```

You're missing a closing `)`

Also [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

And do not store user passwords using MD5, this is nearly as bad as plain-text

Comment: +1 for also mentioning the deprecated `mysql_` extension.

Comment: Thanks very much, Im just new to php so i figured this would be a good thing to start with